# Define domain of a function, equation is given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let's say I have

$\frac{d^{2}y(x))}{dx^2}=-\frac{A}{T}$

What can I say about the domain? T is constant,
Given calues for A are 0, 16,0.5

**EDIT:**
I know that the solution is a function whose domain is an open interval.

Boundary conditions: y(0)=19, y(1)=17
The equation can be solved via integration

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Comment: It is the first time I encounter such a problem. Could you give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: any other conditions such as boundary conditions? can you solve the differential equations?

Comment: Yes! Boundary condition y(0) = 19, y(1) = 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon integrating twice, we get a quadratic equation.

You are given the boundary conditions $y(0)=19, y(1)=17$, the boundary would have defined the domain.

The question is how is domain being defined. If it can be a closed interval, then it is $[0,1]$ since $0$ and $1$ are the boundaries. Suppose there are additional restriction such that a domain must be open, then it is $(0,1)$.